# PyCharm's console for exploring variables

Tags: python, pycharm

I was interested to see the inner working of a simple numpy array... So i kept expanding the `_internals_` dropdown, only to see that it goes on (seemingly) indefinitely!

[image: never-ending internals]

Are these autogenerated by PyCharm, or does anumpy array really hold all this "*junk*"?

Comment: Due to my limited knowledge of memory, I am aware that is really can't be turtles all the way down.

Comment: NumPy arrays don't even *have* an `__internals__` attribute. Looks like PyCharm may be making stuff up again.

Comment: Sounds legit ;-)